# C# udpclient.send to fake ip too slow to complete

Tags: c#, udpclient

when i udpclient.send to an fake/unknown ip, the process took a long time to complete(about 2 seconds per call. for 1000 calls it took about 2000 seconds). if i udpclient.send to a known ip, sending 1000 packets took less than 2 seconds.

i was using send for development and this kind of things makes development process took a long time. is there a way to prevent this slowdown? fyi, i did put ip address(not hostname to prevent dns resolve), i did try use udpclient.connect but the problem still persist.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed by now, this is  DNS problem.

In your local machine, you could write in `/etc/hosts` (assuming you are developing on Linux), an entry like:

```
192.168.1.20    target-develop
```

then the resolution of name "target-develop" will take only a moment.

**EDIT**

If you send packets to unknown/fake IP and it takes long time, it could be a firewall's configuration problem.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention im using c# .net 4.0. if this is a dns problem, then why it is still a problem when i did use ip address instead of hostname? i dont really understand.

Comment: apart from standard windows firewall, no, i dont have special firewall.